Assertion Failure: Block Expected on Main Thread in Swift macOS App Using DispatchQueue
A user is experiencing a crash in my macOS app. It was written in Swift and developed using Xcode. The crash report indicates an assertion failure related to dispatch queues, specifically stating that a block was expected to execute on the main thread but wasn’t. I'm pretty new to all this so it's got me a bit stumped.
I don't have access to his computer, and haven't got anything remote set up in the app, so he sent over the crash report. I've had a fair amount of other users use the app on different Macs, with different versions of macOS and different hardware, and it's been fine.
Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT at 0x00000001985ab82c (brk 1)
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
BUG IN CLIENT OF LIBDISPATCH: Assertion failed: Block was expected to execute on queue [com.apple.main-thread]

Thread 4 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.user-initiated-qos
0   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985ab82c _dispatch_assert_queue_fail + 116
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985ab824 _dispatch_assert_queue_fail + 108
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985ab7b0 dispatch_assert_queue + 152
3   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001a0375cd8 islGetInputSourceListWithAdditions + 160
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001a037860c isValidateInputSourceRef + 92
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00000001a03784cc TSMGetInputSourceProperty + 40
6   com.apple.SkyLight              0x000000019d287cbc invocation function for block in key_translate_initialize() + 168
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985a9420 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985aac38 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
9   com.apple.SkyLight              0x000000019d287c10 CGSKeyEventTranslate + 104
10  com.apple.SkyLight              0x000000019d0de2c8 SLEventCreateKeyboardEvent + 264
11  myname.myapp                    0x0000000102696a38 0x1025d8000 + 780856
12  myname.myapp                    0x0000000102677bd0 0x1025d8000 + 654288
13  myname.myapp                    0x00000001025e0628 0x1025d8000 + 34344
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985b7628 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 148
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985a9420 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985ba0d8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 656
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001985ba7a4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198752024 _pthread_wqthread + 216
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000198750d94 start_wqthread + 8

I think, though I'm not 100% sure, that it's happening at this part of my code which executes an AppleScript and processes the results on different dispatch queues:
    func runGetAllTrackNamesAppleScript(script: String, completion: @escaping (Bool, String?) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            if let scriptObject = NSAppleScript(source: script) {
                var error: NSDictionary?
                let output = scriptObject.executeAndReturnError(&error)
                
                if let error = error {
                    os_log("AppleScript execution error: %{public}@", log: .default, type: .error, String(describing: error))
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(false, nil)
                    }
                } else {
                    //os_log("AppleScript executed successfully.", log: .default, type: .info)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(true, output.stringValue)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                os_log("Failed to create NSAppleScript object.", log: .default, type: .error)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(false, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

Or it might be in this part where I also use "userInitiated":
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async(execute: workItem)
        
        self.currentWorkItems.append(workItem)
    }

What is causing the assertion failure in my code? How can I ensure that main-thread-only code runs on the main thread to avoid this crash?
I tried to wrap some of the code in DispatchQueue.main.async blocks to stop it happening but it didn't seem to work. I wanted to come here before ending up getting the user to try loads of fixes that don't work.

"How can I ensure that main-thread-only code runs on the main thread" You can ensure that by not running it on DispatchQueue.global, which uses a background thread.
